# agora.io videochat is showing half video in black the other half show the video

Tags: javascript, video, agora.io

[Video view agora videochat with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgwEh.png)
Agora video chat is showing half black and half video

Comment: Could you please provide more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue if I use AgoraRTS plugin, also check if you are using the same codec: vp8 or h264

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend specifying {fit: cover} when you are playing the video in the element using the .play() function. 
It sizes the video to fit the container while maintaining the aspect ratio.
In case, the above is not the issue and you can't view the full range of the video captured by the media device, then try the steps given in the below-given link:
https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/video_blank#issue-description

Do get back to us if the issue remains unresolved.